# Object not casting shadows on itself

Tags: rendering, objects, transparency

I created a scene, which was mostly a sky of blue with random clouds covering the world, and I want the clouds to look more solid. But rendering the clouds makes them one flat blob. Its just white with no corners to make it look 3D
I messed with the settings to see if I could figure it out, because I had gotten it once before, but nothing worked. As I said, I've figured it out before, but now its not working, no matter what I do.

[image]
[image: This is what its supposed to look like]

[image: Whats with this?]

Comment: Could you add some pictures of your current situation?

Comment: @Carlo pictures added

Comment: Blender Internal or cycles?

Comment: @David Blender Internal

Comment: if the material is not shadeless, it should be the light setup...

Comment: As in.... ?
The character there is shaded, so there are lights.

Answer (score 1):

Ah HA!
The problem was in the options tab, in the materials section for the clouds.
"Traceable" was not selected. The clouds were not being traced. Once selected, it fixed everything.